# Official GPU Miner

Tags: gpu-mining

Are there any plans to create an official GPU miner?  I'm trying to mine pools other than Miner gate and so far the only Miner I was able to get running on my Nvidia card said 10 h/s. I have an 8 core Intel CPU with 16 gigs of RAM. I haven't tested ac CPU miner yet, but I can't see my CPUs having a higher hash rate.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to create "official" one if plenty open-source ones are available.

See the mining wiki [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/MoneroMining/wiki/index) for how to get started and available options for mining software.